# Wrap C++ function that returns MPI communicator using Cython

Tags: python, c++, mpi, cython, mpi4py

I am trying to wrap a C++ function that doesn't take any input and returns the MPI communicator.

Foo.h

```
class Foo{
 public:
  Foo(MPI_Comm _comm){
   _comm = comm;
  }
  MPI_Comm getMPIComm(){
   return comm
  }
  virtual void Foo1() = 0
```

I have tried that following:

source.pyx

```
cimport mpi4py.MPI as MPI
from mpi4py.libmpi cimport *

cdef extern from  Foo.h:
   cdef cppclass Foo:
      Foo(MPI_Comm _comm)
      MPI_Comm getMPIComm()
      void Foo1() 

cdef class pyFoo:
   cdef Foo *thisptr
   def __cinit__(self,MPI.Comm _comm):
      pass
   def get MPIComm(self):
      c_comm = self.thisptr.getMPIComm()
      return <MPI.Comm> c_comm
   def Foo1(self):
      pass
```

This code compiled and I was able to write a python code that inherits this class. However, when I tried to access getMPIComm at the python level, I encountered a segmentation fault and the error given by valgrind is:

```
Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
```

Does that mean that I did not wrap getMPIComm() properly? Does anyone know how I should approach it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you never allocate `*thisptr` and thus getting an access violation when trying to call `getMPIComm` on it. Try to create a `Foo` instance as follows:

```
cdef class pyFoo:
   cdef Foo *thisptr
   def __cinit__(self,MPI.Comm _comm):
      self.thisptr = new Foo(_comm)
   # ...
```

Comment: I am not sure how to allocate *thisptr in this case because of the pure virtual function Foo1 and it brings up a compilation error when I tried doing the pointer allocation. Should this be happening?

Comment: @user279545: Yes that's right. You cannot instantiate an abstract class. But then you cannot use the `this`-pointer at all. Maybe you should wrap a subclass of `Foo` that can be instantiated. Another way is to change the signature of `Foo1` to `virtual void Foo1() = {}`. It depends on your needs.

Comment: If I would like to wrap a subclass of [Foo] in this case, how would I go about doing it? I am still pretty new to cython and trying to figure things out.

Comment: Even in C++ it is not possible to get an instance of `Foo` because it is abstract. This means there should be other classes that inherit from `Foo`. And instead of wrapping `Foo` itself, you can simply wrap the subclasses as you tried above. In this case it will work, because you can instantiate the `thisptr`.